# Parsing custom Tymon\JWT token with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token, jwt

I'm trying to parse a custom `JWT token`. To generate the token i have the following class:

```
public function createToken()
{
    $client = ['sub' => 'u0406'];

    $payload = JWTFactory::make($client);

    $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);

    return $token;
}
```

I get this token and passing it

How can i parse this and get the variable `$client` in another method?
My `parseMethod` is declared like this:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        return $token;
}
```

And it just returns the token string. Not the array.

Comment: I edited the question, it was poorly worded. My bad, sorry. @AniketSahrawat

Comment: @AniketSahrawat declaring anything `global` with that keyword is considered a bad practice in the OOP world.

Comment: I know, this is just a test method. Anyway i need to parse a jwt token.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm Trying to generate a fake custom token in method `createToken` and trying to parte is in the method `create`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @IvankaTodorova. Why are you returning `$client` from `function create` @IvanMoreira, according to me, it must be `$token` right?

Comment: Yes, sorry again. I'm a little bit nervous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this with the following method:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();
        return $token->getPayload()->get('sub');
    }
```

This returns `u0406`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you succeeded in creating your token in the `createToken()` method and you are passing it in a request to the create() method inside which you want to parse that token to get the client object/associative array again.

From what you are wrote, I think you are using the wrong method on the JWTAuth, which is `getToken()`. To do the parsing right, try this

1. Instantiate a $jwtauth object from the JWTAuth class first
2. In your create method access the client/user by using  `$client = jwtauth->toUser($token);`